# Make a type ragged array in a one dimensional array

Tags: arrays, types, fortran

My problem is that there is a subroutine that makes a calculation and generates an array that I don't know the size previously. The best solution I found out was to use a `type(ragged)` and working with various separated allocatable arrays (`station%trac`):

```
module ragged_module
  type ragged
    real,allocatable,dimension(:)::trac
  end type ragged
end module ragged_module 

program chrag
use ragged_module
implicit none
type (ragged), allocatable, dimension (:) :: station
(...)
call calculation(station, othervariables)

call calculus(station1D,othervariables) !station need to be seen as an 1D array here 

end program chrag
```

However, I need to make the variable `station` like a one dimensional array (to pass to another subroutine). If I was working with a 2D array it will be easy, since I know how is the memory access, but in the case of a type I didn't find out.

Is there an easy way to do that? Or should I declare a 1D allocatable array and then pass the values of each component of `station` to this new 1D array after allocating the necessary length? My concern is because I'm working with huge arrays and my old solution was to use `move_alloc` what made my code very slow.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to pack the pseudo-array `station(:)%trac` into a rank-1 array.  I don't think that any 'clever' use of old Fortran tricks, such as equivalencing the first element of a rank-1 array to `station(1)%trac(1)`, are going to work even if your compiler accepts such a declaration.  That type of trick depends on a particular layout of array elements in memory which just won't be guaranteed by the standard.  You could try, but I wouldn't hold out much hope for success.

Depending on your pattern of usage, of writing to and reading from the ragged array, you could adopt a different design such as

```
type :: ragged_array
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: indices
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: elements
end type ragged_array
```

in which all the entries in the ragged array are stored in the rank-1 array `elements`.  `indices`, of course, holds the indices of the start (or end) of each of the 'rows' in the ragged array.  This approach makes populating the ragged array more difficult, and extracting 'rows' from it.  It's horrid if you ever want to adjust the length of any 'row' other than the last.

But it has the merit that all the elements are stored in a rank-1 array, ready for processing in one gulp, and avoids the need to make temporary copies of large arrays while you marshal your data.

You choose, you know your application better than we do.